# Can a function take an argument, and declare it as a global variable?

Tags: javascript, scope

Is it possible in javacsript, to have a function take an argument, and declare it as a global variable? For example, I know that this does not work, but I'm just curious if there's an alternative that works:

```
function newVar(n){
  n = "I'm a global variable"; 
}

newVar("workPls");
console.log(workPls);  //Error: workPls is not defined
```

Comment: And where should get the parameter name?If I understand you, you will pass the name and the function will assign the value?

Comment: you understood correct, Joraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not recommended, but you can do something like this:

```
function newVar(n){
    window[n] = "I'm a global variable"; 
}

newVar("workPls");
console.log(workPls);  // "I'm a global variable"
```

Comment: To elaborate: `window` is the global object and every property of that object is a global variable.

Comment: @FelixKling And also can be accessed without calling object.variable, but only variable.

Comment: In the case of serverside Javascript (e.g. `node`), the global object is named `global`, not `window` (because there are no windows there).

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty interesting approach

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can instead make use of return?

```
function newVar(){
  return "I'm a global variable"; 
}

var workPls=newVar();
console.log(workPls);
```

Comment: That doesn't work because i'm trying to make the argument the name of the variable : /

Comment: Yes however this code still assign a new variable with your chosen name so in this example you would have the same result (variable workPls exists, and the value is the string "I'm a global variable")-